# docker logs --follow or -f don`t work as expected

Tags: docker

On one of the test devices (so not all of them) i discovered that docker logs -f stops streaming logs, so command act exactly the same like without -f flag, i also tried docker --follow but with no success. Does anybody experience same issue? or maybe have idea what can cause this.

Restarting device or systemctl restart docker does not help